# merge remote branches before it gets merged to remote/master?

Tags: git, merge

I use a github hosted open source library.
There is a mature branch `branchA` I want to merge in to my work.

The maintainer probably will merge the branch to his master(upstream/master to me) branch as well in near future.

I wonder if it's ok for me to merge the branch myself to local master.
Wouldn't it cause a massive merge conflict when I merge the upstream/master which also merged the `branchA` in the future?

- edit

How about making a local/branchA from upstream/branchA and make changes to it and merging it to local/master?

Would it be fine as well later when merging in upstream/master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not you'll have a merge "problem" depends on what happens on the upstream master prior to the owner merging in `branchA`.

However, regardless of what happens, once `branchA` does get merged into the upstream master, you can just run the following in your local copy and be "up-to-date":

```
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

This combination will ensure your local copy of `master` points to the same commit as the upstream copy of `master`. Since you would do this *after* the owner merged `branchA` into the upstream `master`, your local `master` will, effectively, still have the changes introduced by `branchA`.

**update**

If you want to make changes to `branchA` prior to merging into `master`, I would recommend you create your own branch based on `branchA` and make your changes there. Having done that, you can then follow my original suggestion and, as long as you keep your local, custom branch around, you'll still have your changes available when it comes time to reset against the updated upstream `master`, and therefore be able to merge those changes into your local master after you reset it.

As a bonus, if your changes are generally useful (i.e., not specific to your situation), you could submit a pull request to the upstream and, possibly, wind-up with your own changes merged into the upstream `master` along with `branchA`.

Comment: what if I have my own changes in master that I want to keep? wouldnt' `reset --hard` wipe out my changes?

Comment: Yes, it would. Given your edited question - that you intend to make local changes to `branchA` prior to merging into your local `master` - you're not going to want to use a `reset --hard`.

Comment: I have my changes in my local/master as well. so, I'll use `git merge upstream/master` instead of your `git reset --hard upstream/master`. Am I still all fine?

Comment: Again, it'll depend on what happens to the upstream between when you forked it and when you try to refresh against it. I definitely recommend you not make changes to tracked, upstream branches when you fork a repo in the future, but git is really, really good at merging, so you might wind up fine either way.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is perfectly fine, git is smart enough to handle the scenario you described.

When git tries to merge commits from another branch, it will find the common ancestor from which the current branch and the branch to be merged diverged, and it will find that both the current branch and the branch to be merged already moved their heads to a nearer common ancestor, so it most probably can be fast-forwarded if you do not introduce modifications that cause conflicts before merging in `upstream/master`.

Answer (score 0):

In anyway you should solve them. The **git mergetool** is awesome, so it will be not so hard.